# Python: How to cluster files by prefix

Tags: python-2.7

I have a set of files:

```
a_a_a_morestuff
a_a_a_morestuff
a_a_b_morestuff
a_a_b_morestuff
a_a_c_morestuff
a_b_b_morestuff
a_b_b_morestuff
```

How can I use python to loop through them and manipulate clusters of files that have the same prefix i.e, a_a_a? I won't know ahead of time how many files I have or how many of the same prefix I will have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

```
import glob
print glob.glob('my_directory/a_a_a*')
```

the output is below where `my_directory` contains many files including `a_a_a_X` where `X` is `1-4`.

```
['my_directory/a_a_a_3', 'my_directory/a_a_a_2', 'my_directory/a_a_a_1', 'my_directory/a_a_a_4']
```

Edit:
If you are not targeting a specific prefix but know the format of the prefix, you can use this code:

```
import os
import re

files = os.listdir("somedirectory")

prefixes = {}

for f in files:
    m = re.search('[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_', f)
    if m:
        prefix = m.group(0)
        print prefix
        if prefix in prefixes:
            prefixes[prefix].append(f)
        else:
            prefixes[prefix] = [f]

for prefix in prefixes:
    print prefixes[prefix]
```

For the case where files is the following array:

```
files = [
    'out-15.03_.03_12.57_001.h5',
    'out-15.03_.03_25.05_001.h5',
    'out-15.03_.03_25.05_002.h5',
    'out-15.03_.03_25.05_003.h5',
    'out-15.03_.03_37.52_001.h5' ]
```

This is the output:

```
['out-15.03_.03_12.57_001.h5']
['out-15.03_.03_25.05_001.h5', 'out-15.03_.03_25.05_002.h5', 'out-15.03_.03_25.05_003.h5']
['out-15.03_.03_37.52_001.h5']
```

Comment: There are hundreds of unknown combinations of prefixes. Any method that requires me to search for a specific prefix seems inefficient.

Comment: For clarification, `a_a_a_1` and `a_a_a_2` share a prefix of `a_a_a_`. They also share a prefix of `a_a_` with `a_a_b_1` for example. Do you want to group all files by a 6 character prefix or any matching prefix?

Comment: I added code for a more general case. Let me know if that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Here is an example of the files I am actually working with. There are three clusters of files here: `out-15.03_.03_12.57`,`out-15.03_.03_25.05`, and `out-15.03_.03_37.52`. But I won't know ahead of time what the number of digits for each will be. `15.03` could be `115.03`, which makes a fixed digit solution impractical as well. Example files:                                                                                                   `out-15.03_.03_12.57_001.h5

out-15.03_.03_25.05_001.h5 

out-15.03_.03_25.05_002.h5 

out-15.03_.03_25.05_003.h5

out-15.03_.03_37.52_001.h5`

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to format the above comment to be more readable.

Comment: I updated my answer to use regular expressions. This way the fixed length is avoided.